# How to retrieve/query values for COM+ Application properties in RegDB

Tags: powershell, com+

I am new to Powershell and looking for some guidance on querying attributes for COM+ Application properties in RegDB. I need to programmatically set "Leave Running While Idle" on one of our COM+ Application.

Below is the sample code to change the identity of COM+ application:

```
    $AppName = "<APPNAME>"
    $comAdmin = New-Object -comobject COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog
    $apps = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
    $apps.Populate();
    $app = $apps | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $AppName}
    $comAdmin.ShutdownApplication($AppName)
    $app.Value("Identity") = "<UserNAme>"
    $app.Value("Password") = "<Password>"
    $apps.SaveChanges()
    $comAdmin.StartApplication($AppName)
```

I am looking for what goes in as an attribute for $app.Value("?") when the value is "Leave Running When Idle".

Here is a reference:

[image]

Comment: Your question is way to generic for us to help you.  Tell us what are you trying to achive with some code which you do not understand.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated my question with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The "Leave running when idle" option on the user interface maps to the "RunForever" property value.

You'll need a line like this:

```
 $app.Value("RunForever") = $true
```

[The documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cossdk/applications#properties) has a complete list of properties.